# Truly vectorize function for numpy array in python

Tags: python, numpy, performance, vectorization

I have the following function, which takes two 1D `numpy` arrays `q_i` and `q_j`, does some calculation (including taking the norm of their difference) and returns a `numpy` array:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as lin

def coulomb(q_i, q_j, c1=0.8, c2=0.2, k=0.5):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    q_i : numpy.ndarray
    q_j : numpy.ndarray
    c1 : float
    c2 : float
    k : float

    Returns
    -------
        numpy.ndarray
    """
    
    q_ij = q_i - q_j
    q_ij_norm = lin.norm(q_i - q_j)
    f_q_i = (k * c1 * c2 / q_ij_norm ** 3) * q_ij
    return f_q_i
```

Now I have a bunch of these `q` arrays stored in another `numpy` array `t` = [q1, q2, q3, ..., qn], and I want to evaluate the function `coulomb` for all unique pairs of `q_i` and `q_j` inside `t` (i.e. for (`q1`, `q2`), (`q1`, `q3`), ..., (`q1`, `qn`), (`q2`, `q3`), ..., (`q2`, `qn`), ... (`q_n-1`, `qn`)).

Is there a way to vectorize this calculation (and I mean really vectorize it to boost performance, because `np.vectorize` is only a `for`-loop under the hood)?

My current solution is a nested `for`-loop, which is far from optimal performance-wise:

```
for i, _ in enumerate(t):
   for j, _ in enumerate(t[i+1:]):
      f = coulomb(t[i], t[j])
      ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here 3 posible solutions, the last one, is a little caothic but uses a vectorization to calculate `n` q vs one. Also is the fastests

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as lin

def coulomb(q_i, q_j, c1=0.8, c2=0.2, k=0.5):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    q_i : numpy.ndarray
    q_j : numpy.ndarray
    c1 : float
    c2 : float
    k : float

    Returns
    -------
        numpy.ndarray
    """
    
    q_ij = q_i - q_j
    q_ij_norm = lin.norm(q_ij)
    f_q_i = (k * c1 * c2 / q_ij_norm ** 3) * q_ij
    return f_q_i    

def coulomb2(q_i, q_j, c1=0.8, c2=0.2, k=0.5):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    q_i : numpy.ndarray
    q_j : numpy.ndarray
    c1 : float
    c2 : float
    k : float

    Returns
    -------
        numpy.ndarray
    """
    
    q_ij = q_i - q_j
    q_ij_norm = lin.norm(q_ij,axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
    f_q_i = (k * c1 * c2 / q_ij_norm ** 3) * q_ij
    return f_q_i    



q = np.random.randn(500,10)
from itertools import combinations
from time import time



t1= time()
v = []
for i in range(q.shape[0]):
    for j in range(i+1,q.shape[0]):
        
            v.append([coulomb(q[i], q[j])])

t2= time()

combs = combinations(range(len(q)), 2)
vv =[]
for i,j in combs:
    vv.append([coulomb(q[i], q[j])])

t3 = time()
vvv = []
for i in  range(q.shape[0]):

        vvv += list(coulomb2(q[i], q[i+1:]))
t4 = time()

print(t2-t1)
print(t3-t2)
print(t4-t3)

#0.9133327007293701
#1.0843684673309326
#0.04461050033569336

``
```

Comment: Thank you, `coulomb2` is exactly what I was looking for! The performance of `coulomb2` against `coulomb1` becomes much better with increasing size of `q`; for 3000 elements in `q`, it was about 100 times faster. Is there maybe a way to also get rid of the outer `for` loop still needed for `coulomb2`?

Comment: I'm not sure... first guess is might exist but to me seems imposible to get rid of this loop

Answer (score 1):

There is a trade off between memory and speed when you want to vectorise these type numpy problems,

Loops over numpy array is slow but there is not much of memory requirement. If you want to vectorize, you have to duplicate and thereby create excess memory and pass it to numpy functions.

One way of vectorizing your function is

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as lin

def coulomb(q_i, q_j, c1=0.8, c2=0.2, k=0.5):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    q_i : numpy.ndarray
    q_j : numpy.ndarray
    c1 : float
    c2 : float
    k : float

    Returns
    -------
        numpy.ndarray
    """
    
    q_ij = q_i[np.newaxis,:, :] - q_j[:,np.newaxis, :] #broadcasting, therefore creating more data
    q_ij_norm = lin.norm(q_ij, axis=2) # this can be zero when qi = qj
    f_q_i = (k * c1 * c2 / (q_ij_norm ** 3)[:,:,np.newaxis]) * q_ij #broadcasting again
    return np.nan_to_num(f_q_i) # this returns a 3D array with shape (i,j,dim_of_q). Here Nan's will be replaced with 0's

t = np.random.rand(500,3)
f_q = coulomb(t, t)

f_q(1,2,:) #will return `coulomb` between q1 and q2
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is faster than my solution only when the size of `q` is small (~<1000). For larger `q`, it becomes about as fast as my initial solution with the nested `for` loops. I think it's because it is calculating a lot of unnecessary values along the way as well. Is there maybe a way to avoid calculating all the unwanted values?